# Androidstudio won't start (JDK rather than JRE)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio. On one PC everything works just fine, but on my desktop, I get the message, I should install the JDK or set a variable for JAVA_HOME.
As I already had the JDK installed (for eclipse) I continued setting a system variable for the JDK:

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Progra~1\Java\jre8
```

I assumed that's the jdk directory, because the JDK install manager provided me this directory.

Now I get to see the android studio splash screen, but it gets interrupted by this message:

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I am running Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

The JAVA_HOME directory you provided is of JRE. Please ensure that there is a folder like this in your computer:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

If it is not there please install JDK.

Then, Reset the environment variable of the JAVA_HOME to correct location.